# asp.net gridview jquery contextmenu

Tags: c#, jquery

I'm trying to display a context menu for each row in the gridview.

The context menu needs to pass specific variables for each row, for example, a unique userid.

I would like the ul to only be on the page once I have passed variables or something

```
<ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
```

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>            
<script src="scripts/jquery.contextMenu.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="jquery.contextMenu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready( function() {

            // Show menu when #myDiv is clicked
            $("img").contextMenu({
                  menu: 'myMenu'
            },
                  function(action, el, pos) {
                  alert(
                        'Action: ' + action + '\n\n' +
                        'Element ID: ' + $(el).attr('id') + '\n\n' +
                        'X: ' + pos.x + '  Y: ' + pos.y + ' (relative to element)\n\n' +
                        'X: ' + pos.docX + '  Y: ' + pos.docY+ ' (relative to document)'
                        );
            });            


      });
</script>


<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
              <asp:GridView ID="Gridview1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                  <Columns>
                      <asp:TemplateField>
                          <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:Image ID="imgPop" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/pop.gif" />  
                          </ItemTemplate>
                      </asp:TemplateField>
                      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="First Name" DataField ="FirstName" />
                      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Last Name" DataField ="LastName" />
                  </Columns>
              </asp:GridView>                                    
        <ul id="myMenu" class="contextMenu">
              <li class="edit"><a href="#edit">Edit</a></li>
              <li class="cut separator"><a href="#cut">Cut</a></li>
              <li class="copy"><a href="#copy">Copy</a></li>
              <li class="paste"><a href="#paste">Paste</a></li>
              <li class="delete"><a href="#delete">Delete</a></li>
              <li class="quit separator"><a href="#quit">Quit</a></li>
        </ul>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Of more use would be the actual HTML output from the page, as opposed to the ASPX, as it seems your question lies mainly within jQuery.

I'm still not entirely sure when your context menu created, but this would be how you add it the DOM dynamically:

```
$("<ul id='myMenu' class='contextMenu'>").appendTo(selector);
//...selector selects some item in the DOM.
```

I'm not seeing #MyDiv anywhere in the HTML, so maybe you need:

```
<div id='MyDiv'>
```

To bind to a click event:

```
$('#MyDiv').click(function(){
    //do something
});
```

Can you maybe try and be a bit clearer on what you want - even add some pseudocode to your script sample so we can fill in the gaps, for example, where you envisage userid being used.